# How can I test a secured endpoint with Awaitility in Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test-mvc, awaitility

I'm using spring boot and I want to assert an asynchronous side effect by calling a secured endpoint with **MockMvc**.

I have been using **Awaitility**, but apparently the mocked security context is lost when executing in a different thread.

I couldn't find a way of passing the context, I tried with `SecurityContextHolder.setContext()` but it didn't work, I guess spring's MockMvc stores the context in a different way.

```
  @Test
  @WithMockUser(authorities = "admin", username = "user")
  void shouldRunSideEffectAsync() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(post("/foo")).andExpect(status().isAccepted());
    await()
        .atMost(TIMEOUT)
        .untilAsserted(() -> mockMvc.perform(get("/foo")).andExpect(status().isOk()));
  }
```

The GET would return 404 for a while and then 200 when the async task is completed. However this will always return 403 as the **MockUser** info is lost.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it. Security for MockMvc is implemented by [TestSecurityContextHolderPostProcessor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/d545f7ac987806d71f907cd2859167f62bdd6ce7/test/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/test/web/servlet/request/SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.java#L791), which uses the [TestSecurityContextHolder](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/d545f7ac987806d71f907cd2859167f62bdd6ce7/test/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/test/context/TestSecurityContextHolder.java#L60) to set/get the security context. That is just a wrapper around the `SecurityContextHolder`.

So you can use `TestSecurityContextHolder.setContext()` in the awaitility thread and it should work.